# Remove item from List Collection not removing

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, collections

I am working on a collection. I need to remove one item from a collection and use the filtered/removed collection.

Here is my code

```
public class Emp{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
}

List<Emp> empList=new List<Emp>();
Emp emp1=new Emp{Id=1, Name="Murali";}
Emp emp2=new Emp{Id=2, Name="Jon";}
empList.Add(emp1);
empList.Add(emp2);

//Now i want to remove emp2 from collection and bind it to grid.
var item=empList.Find(l => l.Id== 2);
empList.Remove(item);
```

> **The issue is even after removing the item my collection still shows count 2.**
>      What could be the issue?

**EDIT:**

Original Code

```
  var Subset = otherEmpList.FindAll(r => r.Name=="Murali");

   if (Subset != null && Subset.Count > 0)
   {
    foreach (Empl remidateItem in Subset )
    {
       Emp removeItem = orginalEmpList.Find(l => l.Id== 
                                          remidateItem.Id);
                    if (removeItem != null)
                    {
                        orginalEmpList.Remove(remidateItem); // issue here

                    }
      }
    }
```

> It is working fine. In actual code i was removing remediateItem. remediateItem was
>   same type but it belongs to different collection.

Comment: Can you show us your actual code? As it is, this wouldn't compile. What you've provided (when it is fixed), works.

Comment: Is your problem in removing the item from the collection or updating the UI? Maybe the item is removed from the collection successfully, but the UI is not updated.

Comment: Yeah. When I run the code it seems to work, when you fix the compile errors.

Comment: I need to filter many based on other collection. Now using a loop. updated code. Is there any other way to do?

Comment: @Murali I do not see a reason to delete the question. There are answers to this question, please mark either one of the answers as a proper answer, or add your own answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are passing the objects to `Remove` which are not in your list you are trying to *remove* but copy of your object in *other the list*, that is why they are not being deleted, Use [List.RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method to pass the predicate.

```
lst.RemoveAll(l => l.Id== 2);
```

If you want to remove many ids in some other collections like array of ids

```
int []ids = new int[3] {1,3,7};
lst.RemoveAll(l => ids.Contains(l.Id))
```

Comment: Is't this will remove all from the list but he want to remove only one

Comment: I have given the condition inside, it will remove only which fulfil the condition given as parameter.

Comment: I need to filter many based on other collection. Now using a loop. updated code. Is there any other way to do?

Comment: if you want to remove thoes having name Murali then you can do like lst.RemoveAll(l => l.Name== "Murali")

Comment: Actually i will be removing based on Ids. they are unknown. so looping

Comment: what to do if need to remove more than 2 Ids? will it remove all?

Comment: You need to pass the ids to predicate check my updated answer, I had already added to remove ids in array.

Answer (score 2):

This original code you have pasted, works perfectly. its removing the items accordingly.

```
List<Emp> empList = new List<Emp>();
Emp emp1 = new Emp { Id = 1, Name = "Murali" };
Emp emp2 = new Emp { Id = 2, Name = "Jon" };
empList.Add(emp1);
empList.Add(emp2);

//Now i want to remove emp2 from collection and bind it to grid.
var item = empList.Find(l => l.Id == 2);
empList.Remove(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int removeIndex = list.FindIndex(l => e.Id== 2);
if( removeIndex != -1 )
{
    list.RemoveAt(removeIndex);
}
```

Try this may be work for you

Answer (score 0):

You wrote your lambda wrong. It should be this way

```
var item=empList.Find(l => l.Id== 2);
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated question. by mistake i typed like that here. But in code it its correct and building

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this blow the menthod Remove():

`orginalEmpList.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question was about how to remove an element from a generic list. It is not about EF and saving records into database.